# Combine known and arbitrary interfaces into a new type

Tags: typescript, rxjs

Consider the following interface:

```
export type SearchDisplayName = {
  name: string;
}

export interface LiveSearchInterface {
  doSearch(params: any): Observable<SearchDisplayName[]>;
}
```

And the implementation looks like this:

```
class MyClass implements LiveSearchInterface {
      doSearch(params: any): Observable<SearchDisplayName[]> {
        return this.http.get(...)  // returns User[]
          .pipe(
              map<User[], SearchDisplayName[]>((rows) =>
                rows.map((row) => {
                    row.name = row.firstName + row.lastName;
                    return row; // this line gives me an error
                }
              )
          );
      }
}
```

This code produces the following error "Property `name` is missing in type User but required in type SearchDisplayName" and it seems reasonable.

But the question is - how to correctly define `LiveSearchInterface` to tell the compiler that returned type is an array of User & LiveSearchInterface interfaces?

I tried something like this

```
export interface LiveSearchInterface {
  doSearch<T>(params: SearchType): Observable<(T & SearchDisplayName)[]>;
}
```

And implementation

```
doSearch<User>(params: any) {/* function body as above */}
```

But it says "Property `name` does not exist in type User"

Comment: You are assigning `name` property to a `User` interface. If `name` isn't available on the User, it is a proper error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumptions based on your code:

- By `Observable` you mean the one from RxJS
- `http.get` returns `Observable<User[]>`

So here is a possible solution:

```
export interface LiveSearchInterface {
  //                                 v intersect both types
  doSearch(params: any): Observable<(SearchDisplayName & User)[]>;
}

class MyClass implements LiveSearchInterface {

  doSearch(params: any) {
    return this.http.get(/*params...*/).pipe(
      map(rows =>
        rows.map(row => ({
          ...row,
          name: row.firstName + row.lastName
        }))
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your assumptions are correct, though, the suggested solution is not what I am looking for. In fact, you just tricked the compiler to supress the error. My question is how to modify the original interface.

Comment: I don't understand, what you mean by tricking the compiler - there are no hacks here. This answer is a possible solution for your requirement "tell the compiler that returned type is an array of User & LiveSearchInterface interfaces". As you now added a more complete example with the `LiveSearchInterface ` interface in the class code, we can do the type change in the interface itself instead of annotating the method return type (see updated answer)

Comment: You should know that Object.assign, as long as object spread operator, is not type safe, as TS treats it as any, that's why your solution is not relevant. While I am looking for a way to avoid Object.assign or spread operator. I want to find a correct interface notation based on generics, because it is not always User type there.

Comment: "You should know that [...] TS treats [spread] as any". Huh? Even generic spread expressions [produce intersection types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/28234), that statement is not quite true. "I am looking for a way to avoid Object.assign/spread. I want to find a correct interface notation based on generics" Then say that in your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and formulate a [complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so others have chance to suggest an appropriate solution. I regret I am out here. Good luck, cheers!

Comment: My question is clear enough, it says `... how to correctly define LiveSearchInterface ...` but not `how to trick the compiler to accept any output type`

Comment: To me, @bela53 answer is right. The return is being defined as an [Intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) of a `User` and `SearchDisplayName` (granted there might want to be more safety measures taken). There is not suppression of anything going on here.

Comment: Okay seems like my mistake, after all